# Wordpress display a page automatically

Tags: wordpress

in WordPress how can we display a page automatically as children of that page?

the thank you page should be displayed automatically by adding **thank-you/** at end of any page.

eg. display https://example.com/thank-you/ page by adding this at the end of URL https://example.com/test/thank-you/

Answer (score 0):

Just check "Page Attributes" in the right sidebar of a page in **edit mode**. You should find there a "Parent Page" dropdown, which you can use to set `test` as a parent of `thank-you` page.

Comment: I want to do this with all pages. not with the single one

Comment: @RahulSawant you are clearly in a wrong website asking for help and you clearly do not understand the way things work both in Wordpress and Permalinks.